# Create Multiple apps of the same project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, dynamic-content

I have been searching a lot for the best practice for my problem and didn't find anything useful so far.

**My problem is:**
I have platform that create E-commerce apps for the user and than we publish it for the users on the play store. 
NOTE: each app have different name and maybe different google account.

Every time there's bug fix or new feature, we need to copy paste the same code in every project and then upload them again to the store.

**My question is:**
Is there's smarter way to deal with this ? i mean what if we have 100 app of the same project, that will be pain to update the code in all of them and than upload all APK's again.

Maybe there's way to update the classes and content dynamic ? or even some tool that can organize the whole thing or manage uploading the APK's ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to copy paste the same code in every project and you don't even need different google account.There is a process called white labelling apps in which you can manage unlimited apk from a single project. Just add all the clients in product flavours in gradle file with different application id. Follow the link attached for detailed procedure of white labelling

https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf

Comment: do i need to create different modules first, and copy the code in them ?

Comment: no, just create new folder with client app name and add only those resources which will be different from your main and add that client under product flavours in app based gradle