# Android Studio common parent project between projects

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create two identical applications, with the same actvity classes and java classes, and the only difference between those apps is the `strings.xml` file, `assets` folder with some images, a `.json` file which is in the `app` folder, `gradle` file which contains the version and the application id, and one java util class file.

So, instead of copy paste the whole project twice, and then when I want to change something I need to change it twice, I want to create like a `parent` project, with all the activites and layout xml files and basiclly all the common stuff, and then two mini projects that contains only the small differences.

Then when I'll need to change something I can change it only once and build the projects.

How can I implement this common/parent project in android studio?

Comment: Android gradle plugin is that you look for. You can use flavors for different projects - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350936/create-multiple-apps-of-the-same-project/

Answer (score 0):

Add flavors to your app gradle file

```
productFlavors {
    firstApp {
        applicationId "FirstApp"
    }
    secondApp {
        applicationId "SecondApp"
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can I use different storekeys for each apk in that way? it should be different apps

Comment: Different apps can use the same store keys. But if you need different, I don't know another ways in this case.

Comment: I suppose plugin support this case too. Try find out